Taking limits on a parameter in a differential operator
I'm working on a physics problem and I have a mathematical question with this ODE system
\begin{equation}
L_{\epsilon}u(t) = \frac{d^2 u(t)}{dt^2} + (2 + 3\epsilon)\frac{u(t)}{t^2} = t^{-3(1+\epsilon)}
\end{equation}
If you are curious, $u(t)$ is related to metric perturbations of gravity and $\epsilon$ is the slow-roll parameter of slow-roll driven cosmological inflation.
The parameter $\epsilon$ on which $L_\epsilon$ depends should be small, and I take it to be $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$. The solution of the ODE is
\begin{equation}
 u(t) = c_1 t^{ 1/2\left(1+\sqrt{3(3+4\epsilon)}\right)})+c_2t^{1/2\left(1-\sqrt{3(3+4\epsilon)}\right)} + \frac{t^{-(1+3\epsilon)}}{3\epsilon(2+3\epsilon)} 
\end{equation}
And the limit $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ of the inhomogeneous term diverges and has a $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ in its series expansion. The reason for this is that when I solve the inhomogeneous system using variation of constants, integrating the conmutator $G(x,s)$ gives the next term
\begin{equation}
    \int t^{-\frac{5}{2}-3\epsilon+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3(3+4\epsilon)}} dt
\end{equation}
This is a logarithmic integral if $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, and a power-law integral with a term of the form $\epsilon^{-1} x^{-\epsilon}$ if not. Then the solution diverges in the $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ limit in which I am working.
However, the solution of the differential equation $L_0$ (taking $\epsilon = 0$)
\begin{equation}
L_{0}u(t) = \frac{d^2 u(t)}{dt^2} + 2 \frac{u(t)}{t^2} = t^{-3}
\end{equation}
has no divergences and exists, and is simply
\begin{equation}
u_0(t) = c_1 t^2 + \frac{c_2}{t} - \frac{1}{9t}\left( 1 + 3\ln{t} \right)
\end{equation}
If I manually truncate the complete solution by taking away the singular term $1/\epsilon$, then $L_\epsilon \hat{u}=\mathcal{O}(\epsilon)$, where $\hat{u}$ is the truncated solution. This is not valid for me since I am working at second order $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$. Then my question is why a differential system that behaves well in both limits has different solutions and one of them diverges, and if this has to do with the differential operator depending on $L_\epsilon$. Is there a wrong assumption on my part?

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Have you tried expressing the solution in terms of boundary conditions (e.g. $y_0,,y_0'$) in case the definitions of the $c_j$ change in misleading ways when limits are taken? For a simpler example of this, $y_1=0$ solutions of $y'=x^{\epsilon-1}$ rely on $\ln x=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{x^\epsilon-1}{\epsilon}$.

Its all alright, a matter of representation.
The ODE has the solution
$$ u(t)\to \frac{t^{-3 \varepsilon -1}}{(3 \varepsilon +2)^2}\ + \ c_1 t^{\frac{1}{2} \left(1+i \sqrt{12+ \varepsilon 7}\right)} \ + \ c_2 \ t^{\frac{1}{2}\left(1- i \sqrt{12 \varepsilon +7}\right)}$$
The limit yields
$$\lim{\epsilon \to 0} \left(\frac{t^{-3 \varepsilon -1}}{(3 \varepsilon +2)^2}+c_2 t^{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{-12 \varepsilon -7}+1\right)}+c_1 t^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-12 \varepsilon -7}}\right)=c_2 t^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i \sqrt{7}}{2}}+c_1 t^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i \sqrt{7}}{2}}+\frac{1}{4 t}$$
The ODE with $\epsilon=0$ yields
$$u(t)\to \frac{1}{4 t}+\sqrt{t} \left(c_2 \cos \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{7} \log (t)\right)+c_1 \sin \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{7} \log (t)\right)\right)$$
In Mathematica convert the trigonometrics to powers
 Assuming[t>0,
  1/(4 t)+
   Sqrt[t] (Subscript[\[ConstantC], 2] Cos[1/2 Sqrt[7]   Log[t]]+
  Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1] Sin[1/2 Sqrt[7] Log[t]])//
 TrigToExp//PowerExpand//FullSimplify]/.
 { (I Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1]+Subscript[\[ConstantC], 2])->2C[1],
 (-I Subscript[\[ConstantC], 1]+Subscript[\[ConstantC], 2])-> 2C[2]}//
  Expand

$$c_2 t^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i \sqrt{7}}{2}}+c_1 t^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i \sqrt{7}}{2}}+\frac{1}{4 t}$$

Thank you both!
It is true that this is only a problem of choosing the integration constants, or a representation problem. Apparently the solutions are different, but this is not true. Using Mathematica to express $u(t)$ and $u_0(t)$ as a function of the initial conditions at $t=1$, $u(1)$ and $u'(1)$, they match at order $\mathcal{O}(1)$ and there is no $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ term. In particular, the $\epsilon$ series of $u(t)$ is
\begin{equation}
u(t) = \frac{t^3 (3 \text{u(1)}+3 \text{u'(1)}+1)-3 \ln (t)+6 \text{u(1)}-3 \text{u'(1)}-1}{9 t} + f(u(1),u'(1),t)\epsilon + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)
\end{equation}
And the zeroth order term is the solution of $L_0 u_0(t)$, if we choose the same initial conditions for both problems.
